# pathFor returning empty href

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I've done quite a bit of searching and testing on what I feel should be pretty straightforward, especially since it is working on other routes:

```
<a href="{{ pathFor 'categoryList' }}">{{post.category}}</a>
```

Here is the Iron Router route:

```
Router.route("/category/:category", function() {
this.render("categoryList", {
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe("posts");
    },
    data: function() {
        Session.set("categoryName", this.params.category);
        return { 
            posts: Posts.find({category: this.params.category})
        }
    }
});
}, {
    name: 'categoryList'
});
```

When I load a post with that HTML / Spacebars, the href is empty. I've tried declaring a name for the route, and it just comes up empty. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: First, you need to name your route so pathFor can know what you want, and second you need to pass parametr which will work as :category. It is all in guide

Comment: as per the guide, iron router will try to guess the name, and in this sense it seems the guess should be correct, as the template rendered is the same name as the path i reference in the template.

anyway, the result is the same if i declare a name, as you can see in the edit above: empty href

Comment: You forget about the second part, your route has variable :categroy which you didnt define anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the parameter for the route in the pathFor.

```
<a href="{{ pathFor 'categoryList' category=post.category}}">{{post.category}}</a>
```